# How do I get to the options in nvlc?

Tags: command-line, vlc, ncurses

I recently found out about the ncurses vlc command line interface, **nvlc** and tried to access the options with no success; the *nvlc -option* command as the help manual suggested didn't do anything

I'm trying to make the *nvlc --nocolor* command permanent to solve a terminal transparency issue.
Does anyone know how to get to the options ?

Answer (score 2):

Try `nvlc --no-color` to run in mono mode.

I usually run `vlc -I ncurses --no-color`, gives the same result.

To persist this mono color mode, best to make a shortcut in your path, and run that instead. This should do:

```
#! /bin/sh
# run nvlc in monochrome mode
gnome-terminal -x nvlc --no-color
```

put this in your path, like `/usr/local/bin/vlcmc` (for vlc MonoChrome or whatever you prefer) and make the file executable. Use sudo to edit this file. It should now be executable like any other app.

From here you can also pass the `--window-with-profile=[PROFILE]` option to terminal, so you can customize the colors/fonts/transparency for your nvlc instance.

Comment: the executable is up and running without complication, thanks a lot it looks like what i wanted to - one more thing, how can i run it from the terminal ? It would be perfected if i could run this new instance of nvlc in the terminal instead of clicking the executable

Comment: clicking? If you place the above code in an executable file within your path (ie /usr/local/bin/vlcmc per example) then you can run 'vlcmc' from the terminal like any other command. try it ;)

Comment: Alternatively, alias nvlc='nvlc --no-color' in your .bashrc. That would also work.

Comment: When I see "clicking", I immediately think of a Windows user (or virgin Linux user). +1 on the --no-color, been looking for that everywhere!